# Clicking a link using rspec and capybara doesn't load the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, click, capybara

In Rails 3.2 I'm using rspec (2.11.0) and capybara 1.1.2 (and have not installed webrat) and it's doing something strange when I click a link on my web page.

I'm trying to click on link on my home page to go to another page.  Below is the basic rspec test.

```
it "should go to agents page" do
  visit 'home'

  #puts page.body
  #links = page.all('a')
  #links.each do |l|
  #  puts l.text
  #end

  page.find_by_id('menu_agents').click

  puts page.body
  #<various content asserts on page currently commented out>
end
```

I basically go to a page, grab a link and click

The link exists.  As you can see from the commented out statements I've confirmed by looking at the page in the console and also looking at the list of links.  I've tried clicking not only with the link above, but also using `click_link` and referencing the id.  Looking at both the code and the html of the page when I run the code I see the id of the element.

In all cases I get the following result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

When running the software with `rails s` clicking the link does load the correct page.  Likewise when I visit the home page in the test it loads correctly as well, since when I print the body to the console I see the right html.

It seems like something is going wrong with the page load when I click the link and the page load has some type of failure (although the test itself does not fail).  Any ideas?

Comment: What assertions do you have commented out, and what exactly is the problem if the test is not failing?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. The commented out assertions are things like: page.has_content('Keywords'). That does fail. That content is indeed on the page when I view it when running the application but as noted above, the page is not loaded. The result shown above is the entire content of the page--just the DOCTYPE listing and no actual page content.

Comment: are you using any kind of javascript on this page? Try running the test with :js => true  (don't really know why that would cause the error your seeing but it's worth a try)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

Page load will take some time. Use **sleep** function. It makes some time to wait.

Then use **page.find("#menu_agents").click** instead of **page.find_by_id('menu_agents').click**

Verify menu_agents id name is not present any other places in result page.

**Note: make sure menu_agents id is unique.**

```
it "should go to agents page" do

  visit 'home'

  sleep 5

  page.find("#menu_agents").click

  puts page.body
  #<various content asserts on page currently commented out

end
```

Comment: probably `sleep`. find will retry until it finds an element.

Answer (score 0):

I had intermittently failing tests because sometimes capybara would try to click on something before the element had loaded, hence it couldn't find it and the test would fail.

I refactored my code to tell capybara to *find* the element before trying to click on it.

Here's two examples. I changed this:

```rb
click_button 'Submit' 
check('booking_accept_waiver')
```

to this:

```rb
find_button('Submit').click
find('input[type="checkbox"][id="booking_accept_waiver"]').check
```

Now capybara waits for those elements to be present before interacting with them and the tests no longer intermittently fail.